# Evaluating relative importance for a group of independent variables

Tags: multiple-regression

I have done a multiple regression analysis of a group of design variables for a system I am analyzing.  From this I determined the standardized regression coefficients.  All of the variables fall into one of two groups, architectural variables and control variables.  I would like to determine the relative importance of each group of variables, so that I can make a claim to the effect of "the architectural variables are twice as important as the control variables for this system".  Is it acceptable if I simply sum the standardized regression coefficients from all the variables in each group and compare these two numbers?

Comment: I have similar problems, look forward to hearing comments on this problem.